# Find control in javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I have a dynamic html table generated using javascript. the table contains diffrent controls like textbox,dropdown box which has custom attributes.How can I loop through all the controls present inside this table and find the control whose custom attribute matches to some value?

Comment: Would be easier to see your markup, or at least a part of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you all the form elements inside your table ([`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)):

```
var $formElements = $('#tableid').find(':input');
```

You can filter with an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
//will select every form element having a data-custom attribute set to 5
var $formElements = $('#tableid').find(':input[data-custom="5"]');
```

Please see the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JHk7k/). For my examples I used [HTML5 data- attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), but the code will work with any attribute you need.

OR you can use the [`filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to write a function that filters your elements:

```
var $formElements = $('#tableid').find(':input').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-custom') == '5';
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo with filter()](http://jsfiddle.net/JHk7k/1/)

Comment: "whose custom attribute matches" I think your selector is not finding custom attributes

Comment: $formElements.each(function () {
    //How can I get the control whose custom attribute value is "x" ?
});

Comment: @sharmila Please see my updated answer. I misunderstood your question at first glance. An attribute selector is your best choice here. I will add a demo very soon.

Comment: inside the each() function just test on the `$(this).attr("data-custom")` value

Comment: I tried like this. But it threw exception<html 
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var formElements = $('#fos').find(':input').filter(function () {
            return $(this).attr('data-custom') == 5;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fos">
        <input type="text" data-custom="5" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" data-custom="2" />
        <select data-custom="5">
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @sharmila 1. Put the script into `$(document).ready()`, the DOM is not ready yet when your script runs 2. Don't forget to include jQuery :).

Comment: How can I get the control based on two custom attribute value? x and y?

Comment: @sharmila Read the links I have provided. Learn how to use the manual. With the `filter()` method, you can filter on anything. Just join the two conditions with a logical operator. Sorry, but from here, you have to show some self-sufficiency. Or ask a new question if you are that stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/DSqZr/1/

```
function getControl(_value){
    $("#panel :input").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("custom") == _value){
           return  $(this);
        }
    })​
}

var selectedCrl = getControl(1);
```

Comment: I want to return the specific control (instead of alert) whose custom attribute value is 1. How can i do it?

Comment: Thanks.How can I get controls which is dropdown box? if it is a dropdown box then I need to change selecteditem.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

Check the example it is probably very close to what you need which is finding `input` & `select` elements with certain attribute values

Answer (score 0):

Give them a class `.control` and:

```
$('.control[attribute=value]')
```

Check [Selectors API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more on attribute selectors.